# jQuery dataTables : IDs gone with fnAddData

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following which moves rows between two jquery datatables, thing is my components lose their IDs when moved which I need to refer by, any ideas?

```
stockTable.on('click', '.toggle' ,function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
    catalogTable.fnAddData(addRow);
    stockTable.fnDeleteRow($row.index());
});
```

Take a look:
**http://jsfiddle.net/E3ZQZ/**

Comment: What IDs? Can you be more specific please? By the way your code doesn't delete moved row. You have to use like this `stockTable.fnDeleteRow($row.get(0));`

Comment: I mean <tr id="1"> for example. btw thanks for the tip, fiddle updated. http://jsfiddle.net/E3ZQZ/5/